# Microsoft Open XML unsaved file

Tags: excel, openxml, vba

Is it possible, through VBA, to get the Open XML definition of the current, unsaved workbook (without saving it)?

Carlos

Comment: did my answer help or would it be tidier if I deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

For playing around with `xml` files in `Excel` I've been using the free tool `Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office`. I've been using this to customise the ribbon in Excel. The tool looks very simple:

[image]

An example of a customization looks like this:

[image]

Pretty sure I downloaded the tool from here:
[http://openxmldeveloper.org/](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)